# How to make the delete button move from edittext to the previous one

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

So I have a little problem with my `AndroidStudio` project. 
Lets say I have 3 `EditText`s. Each one has max length of 1 letter and when I type in its automatically moves to the next one. The problem is once I press delete button to move back it doesn't do anything. I used `TextWatcher` and everything, but its either isn't doing anything or deletes all when I use key listener.

Comment: post your java code

Comment: i put this in the afterTextChanged :  if(ed2One.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    ed2One.clearFocus();
                    ed1One.requestFocus();
                }

Comment: sorry didn't understand your question

Comment: I have 3 edittexts,each has maxlength of 1. When I type in a letter it goes to the next edittext as it should. but lets say I came to the second  edittext and I decided to go back to the first one, I press back and it doesnt do anything. it stays in place.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a TextWatcher, I think setting key listeners would help in checking if delete event is true and handling it there. It still needs to be fixed since when you keep pressing on the delete button, it jumps to the previous EditText but does not resume the deleting process. For example, set each EditText's maxLength to 1 in case of a pin code input view.

```
private var BOX_SIZE : Int = 1
private var mIsLastBoxReached : Boolean = false

editText_first_box.setOnKeyListener { view, i, keyEvent ->
    if(editText_first_box.length() == BOX_SIZE && keyEvent.keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
        editText_second_box.isEnabled = true
        editText_second_box.requestFocus()
    }
    false
}

editText_second_box.setOnKeyListener { view, i, keyEvent ->
    if(keyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && editText_second_box.length() == 0){
        editText_first_box.requestFocus()
        editText_second_box.isEnabled = false
    }else if(editText_second_box.length() == BOX_SIZE && keyEvent.keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
        editText_third_box.isEnabled = true
        editText_third_box.requestFocus()
    }
    false
}

editText_third_box.setOnKeyListener { view, i, keyEvent ->
    if(keyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && editText_third_box.length() == 0){
        editText_second_box.requestFocus()
        editText_third_box.isEnabled = false
    }else if(editText_third_box.length() == BOX_SIZE && keyEvent.keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
        editText_fourth_box.isEnabled = true
        editText_fourth_box.requestFocus()
    }
    false
}

editText_fourth_box.setOnKeyListener { view, i, keyEvent ->
    if(keyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && editText_fourth_box.length() == 0){
        editText_third_box.requestFocus()
        editText_fourth_box.isEnabled = false
        mIsLastBoxReached = false
    }else if(editText_third_box.length() == BOX_SIZE && keyEvent.keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
        //TODO what to do if card number inserted
        mIsLastBoxReached = true
    }
    false
}
```